# Use DrawText to draw end of a text

Tags: vb.net, textrenderer

Is `TextRenderer.DrawText()` capable to draw the end of a text when destination rectangle is too small?

`TextFormatFlags.Bottom` didn't helped me.

In others words: how to clip text on its top edge?

Comment: On it's top edge?  Not sure I understand.  A picture might help.

Comment: Of course, here is it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Se21.png (without panel nor label, just DrawText).

Comment: Just use a negative Y-coordinate, you get it from MeasureText.  Getting the top line clipped perfectly, no.

Comment: However I would have been able to use MeasureText to get height of a line from the same font, and clip accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an in memory bitmap that is the size of the "overflow area".  Draw your text string to this overflow area with a -Y coord that so that it draws off the top of the image that lines up with the area you want to clip to.  You now have the overflow text in an image that you can paint where you want it.

For example, if you want to draw text that is 100 pixel high in an area that can only show 75 pixels, create a 25 pixel high image, and draw your text to that image at y=-75.

Comment: You resolved my problem! But, as GDI DrawText() method seems not to be compatible with in-memory rendering (because of unsupported subpixel antialiasing), I will not use it. Have to find other way. Rendering with DrawString don't give the same visual result.